# Spring dependency not loading?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a dependency for the spring framework version 4.3.2.

I'm getting this error: (Updated to include full stack trace)

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:736)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 24 more

Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Ambiguous argument values for parameter of type [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations] - did you specify the correct bean references as arguments?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:736)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The spring api has the 'org.springframework.cache.transaction' in the dependency but I don't see it in the Maven libraries. I've tried removing and adding the dependency but it doesn't show up

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To be more specific the exception came when I tried to declare a bean for RedisCache.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.8.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction

root-context.xml

```
<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
    c:template-ref="redisTemplate" />
```

Comment: Can you show your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Please share details so that one can reproduce the error

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError also occurs if one has issues in the static block of the offending class. Please post the full stack trace including all the "Caused By"  blocks

Comment: Explain the issue with details...

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-transaction-transactionexception/

Comment: @alayor I updated it to include the pom.xml

Comment: @chomnoue I updated the question to show more information.

Comment: @JaySmith I saw that and included the dependency but no luck

Comment: @JoydipDatta updated to include full stack strace

Comment: Actually it seems that the original error is gone. There is a new one now. I apologize, I think I can figure this one out.

Comment: I appreciate the help everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a constructor to Bean `RedisCacheManager`.

Something like this:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager" c:template-ref="redisTemplate" 
 <constructor-arg value= redisOperations />
</bean>
```

And you should declare `redisOperations` as a bean as well.

Comment: Yes, when I changed the constructor parameter to: c:redis-operations-ref="redisTemplate" the error is now gone. I saw this from another question as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A NoClassDef error is generally when you do have the class during compile time but it isn't present during runtime. Please check your maven dependencies thoroughly for any jar conflicts. This might be a possible cause for the NoClassDef. Check your pom.xml and navigate to the dependency hierarchy tab to verify if you do not see the same jar with different versions twice.

If you do have jar conflicts you would have to remove one of them based on your requirement of using the specific version

you can try below dependency :-

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I have that dependency already in my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cache/transaction/AbstractTransactionSupportingCacheManager
```

Here you are giving path of class instead of giving **fully qualified name**

**try to give fully qualified class name...**

class name should be like this---- **org.springframework.cache.transaction.AbstractTransactionSupportingCacheManager**

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I don't even really call the class myself. I tried creating the bean with that class name and still got the error. I'm actually not seeing this specific error anymore though, and I removed the bean

Comment: @LR07 provide that bean tag

Comment: <bean class="org.springframework.cache.transaction.AbstractTransactionSupportingCacheManager" />

Comment: And I wasn't even sure if that was going to do anything. I don't have the bean tag in my context.xml at the moment and the error is gone. It's just a new one is showing. But I think I'm heading the right direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146556/discussion-between-navnath-adsul-and-lr07).